# 404 error when deploying through TomCat manager connected with IIS 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, iis, deployment, tomcat7

We are having issues with our deployment. We need to deploy to a remote TomCat-container which is accessed through IIS 8.5 with the TomCat Connector from Apache. We followed the guide at the following resources when we installed the connector:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=376210448#ConfiguringTomcat-ConnectorforIIS8.0(WindowsServer2012orWindows8)-Step1.InstallandConfiguretheAJPConnector
- File size is not too big for IIS 8.5 (the file size is **50mb**)
- http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Of what we can see, the .war file gets uploaded but when it should be deployed, we are returned a 404 page, telling us that the page doesnt exist and the application is not deployed.

Things we have checked and double checked is the configuration for:

- File size limits in TomCat configuration (the file is not too big for TomCat)
- Security Access for the TomCat service user (NETWORK SERVICES), so that TomCat has access to the folders it needs for unpacking the .war etc.
- Alot of other things while we were grasping for some answer

The logs of TomCat and IIS doesnt give a clue to why this issue exists, we can see that we accessed the manager and performed a PUT operation, nothing else... we have set the log level to FINE, still no clue. Logs of IIS does also not give any clues to what the issue is.

We are thinking that the issue lies within IIS 8.5 and the connector but we cant find it.

Thankful for anything that you might think could be a potential issue. Are there any other connectors for TomCat 7.0.55 / IIS 8.5 that might be better?

Thanks / David

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the issue was really related to max upload-sizes in IIS 8.5

We read in the documentation that IIS 8.5 has 2gb as upload limits but as I posted the question above I thought that I just had to double check it. It was set to 30mb... Its always some trivial answer... Im leaving this here in case someone else gets the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, deploying from **maven using tomcat plugin** was returning **404** (*[ERROR] Tomcat return http status error: 404, Reason Phrase: Not Found*).
Indeed, the problem was the "Maximum allowed content length", that was ~30MB.
This value can by changed on: The site > Request Filtering > [Actions Panel] > Edit Feature Settings.

I'm sharing because almost 3 years have passed and this question brought some light to my problem